# Flurry View Setting to show data in Table view

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

Is there any way through which we can get the event details in a tabular format like if I want to see what action the users performing frequently, any specific user data for the user journey etc. rather than viewing each events separately? #flurry

Means rather then viewing in Node view looking for table view

**Example-** add one image where we can see Events in node view

then we can convert into table format view where we can get all data in one view possible.

[image]

Comment: Hello Todd, are you talking about seeing events grouped within a user for user journeys, where oyu could see which events that user performed frequesntly?

Comment: @FlurryAnalyticsSupport those all custom event create by us .. the question can i convert this node view into table to get more information without going inside one event